# Parse, add relation. Unable to encode an association with an unsaved ParseObject

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to add a relation on the table users with the bars on the table bar. The bars already exist on my database but I'm always getting the error "unable to encode an association with an unsaved ParseObject".

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
ParseObject barParseObject = ParseObject.createWithoutData(TABLE_BAR, bar.getBarId());
ParseRelation<ParseObject> relation = user.getRelation(ApiUserMapper.FIELD_LIKES);

if (bar.isFavourite()) {
    relation.add(barParseObject);
} else {
    relation.remove(barParseObject);
}
user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            resultCallback.processResults(bar);
        } else {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: updateFav " + e.getMessage());
            } 
            resultCallback.processError(e);
        }
    }
});
```

bar.getBarId() contains a valid ObjectId already stored in the database, but I also tried querying for that bar before with the same result.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(TABLE_BAR);
query.getInBackground(bar.getBarId(), new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            ParseRelation<ParseObject> relation = user.getRelation(ApiUserMapper.FIELD_LIKES);

            if (bar.isFavourite()) {
                relation.add(object);
            } else {
                relation.remove(object);
            }
            user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        resultCallback.processResults(bar);
                    } else {
                        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Error: updateFav " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                        resultCallback.processError(e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

If I try to add the relation the other way around, it works fine. But I want the relation to be added on the table User.

```
ParseObject barParseObject = ParseObject.createWithoutData(TABLE_BAR, bar.getBarId());
        ParseRelation<ParseObject> relation = barParseObject.getRelation(ApiUserMapper.FIELD_LIKES);
        relation.add(user);
        barParseObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    resultCallback.processResults(bar);
                } else {
                    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error: updateFav " + e.getMessage());
                    } else {
                        Crashlytics.log(LOG_PRIORITY, TAG, "Error: updateFav " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    resultCallback.processError(e);
                }
            }
        });
```

Any hints? Something related to permissions? I'm assuming that the current user is able to write his own data but I don't have any specific setting anywhere in my code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the user is logged in? It looks like the `user.getCurrentUser()` may be returning null, which would explain the sticky error.

Comment: The user is fine. In fact if I try to add the relation the other way around (add the relation to the bar not to the user) is working fine.

ParseObject barParseObject = ParseObject.createWithoutData(TABLE_BAR, bar.getBarId());
        ParseRelation<ParseObject> relation = barParseObject.getRelation(ApiUserMapper.FIELD_LIKES);
        relation.add(user);
        barParseObject.saveInBackground();

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was going on but I deleted my user on the Parse console. I created a new one and now everything it's working fine!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment or upvote yet but I wanted to let it be known that deleting and readding the user also fixed my problem, in case someone else has the same issue.